# The algebraic dual space of a TVS is complete

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

> (Treves Exercise 5.4) Let $E$ be a TVS and $E^*$ its algebraic dual. Provide $E^*$ with the topology of pointwise convergence in $E$. A basis of neighborhoods of zero in this topology is provided by the sets
>   $$W(S,\epsilon) = \left\{x^* \in E^* : \sup\limits_{x\in S} |x^*(x)| \leq \epsilon\right\} $$
>   as $S$ ranges over the family of finite subsets of $E$ and $\epsilon$ over the set of numbers $>$ 0. Prove that $E^*$ is complete.

This is what I have so far:

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a Cauchy filter on $E^*$. Define $\Phi_x:E^* \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $$\Phi_x(x^*) = x^*(x). $$
Then $\Phi_x$ is continuous and linear, which implies $\Phi_x$ is uniformly continuous.
Hence $\Phi_x\mathscr{F}$ is a Cauchy filter on $\mathbb{C}$.
But $\mathbb{C}$ is complete, so there exists a $\lambda_x \in \mathbb{C}$
such that $\Phi_x\mathscr{F} \rightarrow \lambda_x$.
This defines a function $\varphi^*:E\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $\varphi^*(x) = \lambda_x$.

How can I show that $\varphi^*$ is linear so that $\varphi^* \in E^*$? Also, how would I show $\mathscr{F} \rightarrow \varphi^*$?

Comment: I think there is a problem if one truly asks for "full" completeness, that is, for arbitrary Cauchy filters/nets/whatever. I hesitate to suggest that the exercise is inaccurate, but it may be. (I think one can prove that weak duals of infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces and Banach spaces are never "fully" complete, although they are _quasi/locally_ complete, which is sufficient for most applications.)

Comment: @paulgarrett Note that it is the *algebraic* dual, not the topological dual. Thus the topological structure on $E$ is irrelevant.

Comment: @Jochen, ah, thanks, I see.

Comment: @Jochen, so, indeed, the "algebraic dual" might as well be the topological dual to the given vector space with the "initial" topology (colimit of finite-dimensional subspaces), on which every functional is continuous... Ok, I get it... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely on the right track. For $x,y\in E$ and $x^*\in E^*$ you have $\Phi_{x+y}(x^*) = x^*(x+y)=\Phi_x(x^*)+\Phi_y(x^*)=(\Phi_x+\Phi_y)(x^*)$. This yields the additivity of $\varphi^*$ and the same argument gives homogeneity. Hence $\varphi^*\in E^*$. Finally $\mathscr F$ converges to $\varphi^*$ pointwise.

If you know that cartesian products and closed subspaces of complete TVS are again complete you can argue without Cauch-Filters by showing that $E^*$ is a closed subspace of $\mathbb C^E$.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how additivity follows.. Are you using uniqueness of limits (Hausdorff)? Using the linearity of $\Phi$, we get $(\Phi_x + \Phi_y)(\mathscr{F}) =  \Phi_{x+y}\mathscr{F} \rightarrow \varphi^*(x+y)$. Do we have a sum rule for convergent filters, i.e. $(\Phi_x + \Phi_y)(\mathscr{F}) \rightarrow \varphi^*(x) + \varphi^*(y)$?

Comment: Yes. You need $\Phi_x(\mathscr F)+\Phi_y(\mathscr F)\to \varphi^*(x)+\varphi^*(y)$ and uniqueness of limits. The "sum rule" is shown as for sequences (with $\varepsilon/2$ and the triangle inquality).

Comment: Ohh I see. What if E is not Hausdorff? (I don't think Treves requires TVS to be Hausdorff.)

Comment: You only need that $\mathbb C$ with the topology given by the absolute value is Hausdorff.

Comment: Ohh rightt, because the filter is on $\mathbb{C}$, not $E$.. Everything's clear now. Thank you for your help!!